# Migrating huge vc++ 6.0 project to vs2008 is possible?

Tags: visual-c++

Hi I'm newer to this technology. And I also migrate the MFC project to visual studio 2008 which is developed in visual c++ 6.0. If its possible are not? I already start my work on that and face some issues like initialization of variables and inclusion of header files. And some cases it shows the CString error and template error. Can any one suggest its possible are not? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible. It may need a day or two to fix all compiler and linker errors. You will need to fix compiler errors, Unicode stuff, MFC related errors, some deprecated stuff, stricter C++, and many other. But, it is doable, and worth doing.